# Перегрузка функций по типу возвращаемого значения

Tags: c++, c++11

Как перегрузить функции и потом их вызвать в С++ 11:

```
int f() { return 2;}
double f() { return 2.7;}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Перегрузка функций невозможна, если они различаются только лишь типами возвращаемого значения.

Стандарт C++14 13.1/2:

> — Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be overloaded.

Answer (score 8):

Никак. Функции должны различаться чем-нибудь помимо типа возвращаемого значения.

Comment: @Тарас: Функции не могут отличаться лишь типом возвращаемого значения что в старом C++, что в C++11.

Comment: @Тарас в стандарте C++17 ([текущем черновике](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf)) указано специально: "Function declarations that differ only in the return type, the exception specification (15.4), or both cannot be overloaded."

Comment: В [стандарте C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) означенный пункт чуть менее точен: "Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be overloaded". И во всех случаях это **первый же** пункт о сигнатурах, не поддающихся перегрузке.

Answer (score 7):

Возвращаемый тип не входит в сигнатуру функции. Представьте, что у вас есть следующий код:

`auto value = f();`

Каким образом компилятор определит какую функцию вы хотите вызвать?

P.S.: это все же называется перегрузкой функции, а не перезагрузкой

Answer (score 7):

Как уже говорили в других ответах:

1) перегруженные функции должны иметь разные сигнатуры, а тип возвращаемого значения не входит в сигнатуру, значит нельзя перегружать по типу результата.

2) можно сделать шаблон функции, и делать специализации этого шаблона для нужных типов - но это уже не перегрузка, а разные имена функций.

```
template<typename T> T f();
template<> int f() { return 2; }
template<> double f() { return 2.7; }

int x1 = f<int>();
double y1 = f<double>();
```

Однако этот код можно улучшить, так что не придется писать тип параметра шаблона - его можно вывести из типа переменной, в которую записывается результат.
Для этого надо использовать объект, оператор преобразования которого будет выбирать нужную функцию:

```
struct F {
    F() {}
    template<typename T> operator T() { return f<T>(); }
};

int x2 = F();
double y2 = F();
```

Разумеется при этом нельзя писать

```
auto a = F();
```

т.к. тогда неоткуда будет вывести тип результата.

Answer (score 3):

http://ideone.com/bY1Mof

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename typed> typed f() { return 2.7; }

int main(void) { return !printf("%d %f", f<int>(), f<double>()); }
```

Comment: Тогда можно использовать еще один вариант - фиктивные аргументы, например 
`int f(int) { return 2; }` и 
`double f() {return 2.7; }` и при вызове целочисленного `f` вызывать его как `f(0)` - все же запись короче...

Comment: Имхо, тут нет перегруженных вызовов вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё оригинальный способ:
<s>http://ideone.com/xEWMhS</s>
<s>http://ideone.com/rpW3dG</s>
http://ideone.com/GkqRaE

```
#include <cstdio>

//template <typename typed> typed f() { return f<void>(); }
//template <typename typed> typed f() { return f<void>(); return f<int>(); }
template <typename typed> typed f();

template <> int f() { return 2; }
template <> double f() { return 2.7; }

int main(void) { return !printf("%d %f", f<int>(), f<double>()); }
```

Теперь `int` и `double` можно, всё остальное не скомпилируется.

В случае использования закомментированного варианта с одним `return`ом вместо варианта в двумя `return`ами `f<void>()` создаст вечный цикл (ну или переполнение стека, в зависимости от оптимизаций).

Спасибо @alexolut, всё оказалось гораздо проще :)

Comment: Для исключения "вечного переполнения" достаточно добавить специализацию и для `void`.

Comment: @alexolut, как именно, если я хочу compilation error получить в случае использования?

Comment: @alexolut, придумал :)

Comment: Если хочется ошибку компиляции, то достаточно просто не писать реализацию общей версии. `template <typename typed> typed f();`

Comment: @alexolut, круто, не знал.

Answer (score -2):

Никак, используй пространства имен.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace _double
{
    double f()
    {
        return 2.6;
    }
}
namespace _int
{
    int f()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << _double::f() << " " << _int::f() << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нда... Из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно?"